# How to have a admob interstitial ad launch when app launches so it shows up first using swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm trying to find a way to have have an interstitial ad run as soon as my app is clicked on so it pops up right away and can be dismissed. I want to have it so the ad launches before you can do anything in the app so it's done and out of the way and I don't want to have the ads throughout the app. I'm trying to find away to do this with Google admob using swift. If someone could please give me a hand that would be much appreciated.

Comment: great article about that http://notnow.uno/2015/08/26/swift-in-admob/

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment, but I don't have the reputation to post a comment .. yet.

You are **not permitted** to load an interstitial at app launch.

Please refer below:

> Disallowed interstitial implementations
>
> App load or exit
>
> Do not place interstitial ads on app load and when exiting apps as
>   interstitials should only be placed in between pages of app content.
>   Ads should not be placed in applications that are running in the
>   background of the device or outside of the app environment. It should
>   be clear to the user which application the ad is associated with or
>   implemented on.

See : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

It's against Google AdMob's terms of service.